# Can I use "wear off" for tool damaging?

Tags: word-request, word-meaning

In an interview with a Czech neurologist, I've heard that much of the mental health (such as the ability to reason, communicate and process information) in older age mainly depends​ on the amount of informational ballast we create. The argument states that with this additional information, we unnecessarily wear some of the basic mental mechanisms off (Even though there's not​ the effect of "too much memories").

I want to express that the mental processes gradually damage by use. Is the verb "wear off"used correctly here? What if I wanted to say "all tools are being damaged by use", would the phrase fit here?

Comment: *Wear down* and as @JavaLatte says, *wear out* are more common idioms, but *erode* might be more suitable in a formal context. With 'tools', *blunt* (transitive only) is not uncommon: the metaphor is that of taking the edge off a blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wear off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-off) is not the appropriate compound verb, as we use it to describe **a feeling or the effect of something wears off, and gradually disappears**. We might, for example, use it to describe the day after some excessive alcohol consumption like this:

> By lunch-time, the effects of the alcohol were starting to wear off.

A suitable expression might be [wear out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-out-something), which means **to use something so much or for so long that it is no longer usable**, for example:

> He spends so long in that armchair that it's starting to wear out.

If the tools are not completely worn out, you would qualify it, for example with **starting to** as in the above example or by saying that something is **nearly worn out**.